# Xcode (C) "Check dependencies" and "Error: Executable doesn't exist"

Tags: c, xcode, compiler-errors, dependencies

I'm doing a school project in C using xcode. The task is to create a command line application that checks if and how many times a word appears in a text file. So far I've just created the first step of the code, I have set the first argue argument to "hej" even though Im not using the word yet, and because of the first filename is not entered and therefore NULL, I have set it to be an existing file called "hej.txt", in order to test my code as I go.

This bit worked before:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"


struct fileSearch
{
    char *inFile;
    char *outFile;
    char *searchWord;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int index = 0;
    struct fileSearch f;
    f.searchWord = argv[1];
    FILE *searchFile;

    //For-loop to assign filenames
    for(index = 0; index < argc ; ++index)
    {
        if((strcmp(argv[index], "-i") == 0) && argv[index] != NULL && strcmp(argv[index + 1], "-o") != 0)
        {
            f.inFile = argv[index + 1];
        }
        if((strcmp(argv[index], "-o") == 0) && argv[index] != NULL && strcmp(argv[index + 1], "-c") != 0)
        {
            f.outFile = argv[index + 1];
        }
    }

    if (f.searchWord == NULL)
    {
        printf("You didnt enter a search word");
    }

    if (f.inFile == NULL)
    {
        f.inFile = "hej.txt";
    }


    if (f.outFile == NULL)
    {
        f.outFile = "stdout.txt";
    }

    printf("%s & %s & %s", f.searchWord, f.inFile, f.outFile);
    return 0;
}
```

It then printed out the search word, the input filename and the output filename.

Then I added the next step of the code where it would open the text file "hej.txt" and then read the strings and print them.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"


struct fileSearch
{
    char *inFile;
    char *outFile;
    char *searchWord;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int index = 0;
    struct fileSearch f;
    f.searchWord = argv[1];
    FILE *searchFile;

    //For-loop to assign filenames
    for(index = 0; index < argc ; ++index)
    {
        if((strcmp(argv[index], "-i") == 0) && argv[index] != NULL && strcmp(argv[index + 1], "-o") != 0)
        {
            f.inFile = argv[index + 1];
        }
        if((strcmp(argv[index], "-o") == 0) && argv[index] != NULL && strcmp(argv[index + 1], "-c") != 0)
        {
            f.outFile = argv[index + 1];
        }
    }

    if (f.searchWord == NULL)
    {
        printf("You didnt enter a search word");
    }

    if (f.inFile == NULL)
    {
        f.inFile = "hej.txt";
    }


    if (f.outFile == NULL)
    {
        f.outFile = "stdout.txt";
    }

    printf("%s & %s & %s", f.searchWord, f.inFile, f.outFile);

    //Open file and read
    char str[60];

    searchFile = fopen(f.inFile, "r");
    if(searchFile = fopen(f.inFile, "r") == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: There is no file with that name.");
        return -1;
    }

    if(searchFile == NULL)
    {
        printf("The file is empty");
        return -1;
    }

    while(fgets(str, 60, searchFile) != NULL)
    {
        puts(str);
    }

    fclose(searchFile);

    return 0;
}
```

However now it builds the code successfully but when I try to run it, I get this error message:

"error: executable doesn't exist: '/Users/Slattegard/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Coursework-chwsqczjjgxcyegnxgysiaigslvq/Build/Products/Debug/Coursework'
error: failed to launch '/Users/Slattegard/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Coursework-chwsqczjjgxcyegnxgysiaigslvq/Build/Products/Debug/Coursework'"

and  the Issue Navigator gives me this message:

"Check dependencies
warning: no rule to process file '/Users/Slattegard/Documents/Coursework/Coursework/Find.c' of type sourcecode.c for architecture x86_64"

Anyone know where I am going wrong?

Comment: Is the file mode set to executable? Did you successfully build your executable? Clean your directory and compile from scratch.